# Search button moves when clicked

Tags: wordpress, forms, widget

Something is happening with the search button on [my site](http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/). I have one in the top header and one in the bottom footer. The one at the bottom works fine. But the one in the header, when the button is clicked, it moves down and then you have to click it again to initiate the search.

Both are inside widgets (I'm using Wordpress with the Brunch Pro theme). I have no idea what I could have done to cause this. All I've done is change the color of the button in the customizer. What could cause the button to move like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button has additional styles that apply to it on the `:focus` pseudo-class:

```
.widget_search input[type="submit"]:focus
```

It looks like there's a bunch of competing/unnecessary styles that are being overwritten/added when it's focused. Resetting them all would fix it:

```
.widget_search input[type="submit"]:focus {
    width: 38.2%;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Or just remove the `widget_search input[type="submit"]:focus` selector from your `style.css` file (on line 1074):

[image: style.css screenshot]

Comment: I just added the second bit of code you posted to the custom css in my theme and that seems to have fixed it. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in style.css file it moves down because it go larger than div width

```
.widget_search input[type="submit"]:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    clip: auto !important;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px 20px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```